# Stop views overlapping when device is horizontal : Android

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="2.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
        android:textSize="14.0sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff449def"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left|center"
        android:id="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@id/eventvenue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name" />
<TextView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left|center"
        android:id="@id/datetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/eventvenue" />
<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/datetime2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/datetime" />
<ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@id/customlistrowlogo"
        android:padding="5.0dip"
        android:layout_width="80.0dip"
        android:layout_height="80.0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/datetime2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the application is in vertical mode if the text in one of the textviews is too long then it will wrap on to the next line and not cover the image.

However when i am in horizontal mode then the text wont wrap on to the next line but instead gets covered by the image.

VERTICAL ::

```
----------------------------
|                    image |
|text text text tex  image |
|t wraps around tex  image |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
----------------------------
```

HORIZONTAL::

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                              |
|     text                                           image     |
|     text text text text text text text text text teimage     |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
|                                                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

unlike in the vertical one where the text drops to the next line in horizontal mode the text gets hidden behind the picture and doesnt go to the next line

Comment: Your example xml does not really show anything, because all your controls have `wrap_content` which causes to be almost invisible. Please review your example code.

Comment: @rekire what do you mean by that ? not following

Comment: I cannot understand your problem bacause all your controls have a width of zero.

Comment: @rekire see the images above

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate XML file for landscape mode in layout-land folder. Whenever your configuration changes android tries to redraw the layout again.its better to have a layout for landscape view.

Comment: I disagree wich you in general I always try to avoid restarts on rotation this makes more trouble than it helps. There are very rar cases where a soecal layout makes sense IMHO.